# Why is word-wrap not working as expected?

Tags: css

I'm getting very frustrated with the head titles of some of my pages, I have word-wrap: break-all, and for some reason its breaking the word so im left with a letter on its own,

[image]

My css is as follows:

```
.spacing {
  font-size: 22px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0 !important;
  line-height: 28px!important;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

it's become infuriating I've tried word-wrap and word-break but none of them seem to be doing what I ask, any ideas why this is happening on the letters in the word rather than the word its self.

Comment: What's unexpected? *The word-break CSS property is used to specify whether to break lines within words.* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Comment: it is actually working exactly as expected. Your CSS has gone out of its way to enforce that the words can break at arbitrary position and when wrapping is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`word-break: break-all;` signifies that there can be a break between any two letters, even in the middle of a word.  Try `word-break: normal;` (or perhaps even just removing `word-break`) and see if that fixes the issue.

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp)